# SharePoint WebPart Permissions

Tags: security, sharepoint, permissions

Hi I am using the SharePoint namespace for a webpart and I encounter some permission errors when I try to use the System account.  Is there a way I can use a defined user instead of the system account?

Right now I have:

```
SPUserToken sysToken = SPContext.Current.Site.SystemAccount.UserToken;
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(_SPSite, sysToken))
```

I want to be able to use an account on the domain instead of the System account, thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to use RunWithElevatedPermissions to get access to the System account to work, as per the following blog post:

http://solutionizing.net/2009/01/06/elegant-spsite-elevation/

Comment: The question was 'Is there a way I can use a defined user instead of the system account?'

Comment: The question also mentions "I encounter some permission errors when I try to use the System account", i was pointing out one possible reason that may have happened in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SPUserCollection`

```
SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.AllUsers
```

to get all of the users on the site, and get the `SPUser` from there. Once you have the `SPUser` you can get the UserToken.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do?  If you don't use a token, the web will be opened with the same permissions as the current user

```
/* runs as user requesting the web part */
SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Web.site
```

or you can wrap it in the **RunWithElevatedPrivileges** delegate

```
/* runs with admin privileges */         
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
   delegate()
   {
      using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Site.Url))
      {
        //do stuff
      }
   }
);
```